# Area between $\cfrac{x}{\sin(x)}$ and $x\sin(x)$ close to (0,0)

Tags: area, curves

I am trying to calculate the area between $\cfrac{x}{\sin(x)}$ and $x\sin(x)$ that is close to point $(0,0)$ as seen in this picture:

[image: area between curves]

The first step is to find the two points that limit that area. These two curves are interesting because they have many points in common, this is a zoom out of that section:

[image: zoom out of the curves]

So the area I am looking for is:
$$
\int_a^b \cfrac{x}{\sin(x)} - x\sin(x) dx
$$

In order to find $a$ and $b$, I did:
$$
\cfrac{x}{\sin(x)} = x\sin(x) \therefore \sin^2(x) = 1 \therefore \sin(x) = 1
$$
So I assume $a = -\pi/2$ and $b = \pi/2$

Is this correct?

Comment: $\sin^2 x = 1 \implies \sin x = \pm 1$ but otherwise your work looks fine.

Comment: What makes you say you can “assume” that? You must find the points of intersection.

Comment: Did you try integration by parts to proceed?

Comment: I did integration by parts and, even though it is possible to find a solution for the integral, we can't evaluate it because we get a negative square root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

As Rushabh Mehta answered, there is no *simple* closed form for the result.

In fact, using rather comples function
$$I=\int \frac x {\sin(x)}\,dx=x
   \left(\log \left(1-e^{i x}\right)-\log \left(1+e^{i x}\right)\right)+i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{i x}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)$$ where appears the polylogarithm function.

This makes
$$\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2} \frac x {\sin(x)}\,dx=\left( 2 C-\frac{i \pi ^2}{4}\right)-\left(-2 C-\frac{i \pi ^2}{4} \right)=4C$$ and then the result $4C-2 \approx 1.66386$ already mentioned by @Toby Mak in comments.

For the fun of it, a good approximation could be obtained using a series expansion built at $x=0$. This would give
$$\frac x {\sin(x)}=1+\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{7 x^4}{360}+\frac{31 x^6}{15120}+\frac{127
   x^8}{604800}+\frac{73 x^{10}}{3421440}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$ Integrating termwise and using the bounds
$$\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2} \frac x {\sin(x)}\,dx=\pi +\frac{\pi ^3}{72}+\frac{7 \pi ^5}{28800}+\frac{31 \pi ^7}{6773760}+\frac{127
   \pi ^9}{1393459200}+\frac{73 \pi ^{11}}{38539100160}$$ which is $\approx 3.66371$ and the a final value of $\approx 1.66371$.

**Edit**

Looking for an easy to get *approximate* value, I wondered what could give the magnificent approximation 
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$ which was proposed by Mahabhaskariya of Bhaskara I, a seventh-century Indian mathematician (hat is to say more than $1400$ years ago).

It would give
$$I=\int \frac x {\sin(x)}\,dx \approx \int \frac{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}{16 (\pi -x)}\,dx =\frac{1}{16} \left(-2 x^2-5 \pi ^2 \log (16 (\pi -x))+2 \pi ^2\right)$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac \pi 2} \frac x {\sin(x)}\,dx\approx \frac{1}{32} \pi ^2 (10\log (2)-1)\approx 1.82942$$ and then, for the whole problem $\frac{1}{16} \pi ^2 (10\log (2)-1)-2\approx 1.65883$

Comment: Your solution and explanation makes this problem even more interesting than I thought. Why is $4C - 2 \approx 1.66386$? What is `C` in this case and where can I learn more about it?

Comment: @HugoTeixeira. Sorry for that ! As Toby Mak commented, $C$ is Catalan constant.

Answer (score 1):

To find the points of intersection, begin by setting $\frac x{\sin{x}}=x\sin{x}$, which gives us when $x\neq n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$:$$\sin^2{x}=1\to\sin{x}=\pm1\to x=(2n+1)\cdot\frac\pi2\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

In this case, you solely care about the area containing $(0,0)$, whose limit points are $\pm\frac\pi2$. So your integral is $$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} \frac x{\sin{x}}-x\sin{x}dx\sim\color{red}{1.66386}$$

Unfortunately, there is no simple closed form for the indefinite integral, so this approximation will have to do.

Comment: @RusabhMehta I found that the integral is approximately [1.66386237671](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bpqw6p8jzu), which is very close to $4G-2$ (where $G$ is Catalan's constant).

Comment: @TobyMak. This is the exact result.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think we should split the integral up, and somehow prove that $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{x}{\sin x } = 4G$ and that $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} x \sin x = 2$.

Comment: @TobyMak The [Wikipedia's page about the Catalan constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) already mentions the integral identity $G = \frac{1}{4} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{t}{\sin t} dt$.